# How can I improve this Javascript, for attaching events to all elements in page?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, dom-events

I'm developing a web application and I need to capture all events of all elements, I write a code myself, but I need you lovely experts to improve my code's performance as much as you can.

```
// Create mouse event callbacks and an array to store callbacks,
// This array is to prevent creation of callback functions multiple times
var mouseEventCallbacks = {};
var mouseEvents = [
    'mouseover', 
    'mouseout', 
    'mousedown', 
    'mouseup', 
    'click', 
    'mousemove', 
    'contextmenu', 
    'dblclick', 
    'mousewheel'
];

function mouseEventCallback(eventType){
    if(!mouseEventCallbacks[eventType])
        mouseEventCallbacks[eventType] = function(event) {
            self.port.emit('new-event', {
                x: event.pageX + window.pageXOffset, 
                y: event.pageY + window.pageYOffset
            },{
                type: eventType
            });
        }

    return mouseEventCallbacks[eventType];
}

// Attach all events to all elements
var elems = window.document.querySelectorAll('*');

for(var j = 0, s = elems.length; j < s; j++) {
    attachMouseEvents(elems[j]);
}

function attachMouseEvents(element){
    for(var k = 0, s = mouseEvents.length; k < s; k++){
        element.addEventListener(mouseEvents[k],
                                 mouseEventCallback(mouseEvents[k]),
                                 false);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(var k in mouseEvents)` is the wrong way to iterate over an array. Use `for(var i = 0; i < mouseEvents.length; i++)` instead.

Comment: thank you, i've edited my code in question.

Comment: i dont think its faster, because jquery may have some inner overloads that i dont need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of attaching event handler to each element, use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). When event is triggered, it bubles in the DOM up to the body (or the first element that handle the event), so you han handle all events in the body's event handler. Then you have the `event.target` property with the reference to the DOM element that actually triggered it

P.S. I've linked jQuery documentation, but it's general advice and it's not just about using jQuery

Comment: Absolutely what I was going to say - in fact I did say something similar to a coworker the other day, and he noticed that certain events like `"scroll"` on a div with overflow content _don't_ propagate up. So, look out for that. Otherwise, this method should be _far_ more efficient than attaching the same listener to each node.

Comment: is event delegation faster than event binding? if so, why is it faster?

Comment: it is much faster when we speak about thousands of elements - it saves memory and it saves CPU time at the time of the binding (in your code you will iterate over thousand of elements, with an inner loop of 9 iterations to attach the handlers). There is a lot of tests and articles over the net, just search for "javascript bind vs delegation"

Comment: @AramAlipoor Event delegation is generally faster just because binding event handler to _one_ element is faster than binding it to _multiple_ elements. It may make browser slightly less responsive (and therefore subjectively slower) though, since selector matching is checked each time event is generated.

Comment: and is there any way to miss an event? i mean if the first event handler call `stopPropagation()`, can i still know about the event using event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery, and .bind events to all elements by using jQuery Universal Selector, however jquery * selector is extremely slow, and event delegation is preferred over .bind.

```
$("*").bind(events...)
```

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

David Flangan author of JavaScript: The Definite Guide says:

> One of the difficulties of working with events is that IE (until IE9) implements a different event API than all other browsers do. To address this difficulty, jQuery defines a uniform event API that works in all browsers. In its simple form, the jQuery API is easier to use than the standard or IE event APIs. And in its more complex full-featured form, the jQuery API is more powerful than the standard API."

Comment: Is this faster than my code? because i think jquery has some inner processing that i dont need.

Comment: it depends, read this article, it shows differences between jquery event handlers. http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/